# Посоветуйте пожалуйста что лучше изучать

Tags: php, база-данных, framework

Начал задумываться о смене роботы. Столкнулся с моментом что практически везде требуется знание и опыт с одним из фреймворков. Понятное дело надо сначала определится с тем что изучать в хоть начальных рамках. Почитал на форумах о нескольких и не смог найти ответ. Что  лучше начать изучать для начала. Хочу попробовать для собственного развития написать что-то. Плюс есть мысль использовать nosql базу(опять таки чтобы разобраться с чем то новым). Буду признателен если получу совет с чего стартануть. До этого работал только с wordpress, opencart, самописной смs на чистом php и mysql базой.

Answer (score 2):

Если вы работали с cms, то скорее всего, вам стоит получить знания об [ORM](https://www.wikiwand.com/ru/ORM), [git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git) и почитать паттерны проектирования. На счёт фреймворков - вы не найдёте идеального, но вроде бы как с yii2 можно начать, т.к. считается что он лёгкий для новичков.

Comment: С гитом работал. Что такое знаю. Интересная тема была для меня ветки. На yii блог писал из документации. Вопрос не в том что проще, а в том что стоит изучить что б быть востребованным на рынке..

Comment: Востребованы всегда хорошие и крепкие специалисты. Которые "односторонними" не бывают. Крепкая алгоритмическая, математическая и языковая база - вот что реально нужно. А освоить с этим всем какой-то там фреймворк для ваяния страничкек на каком-то там пэхэпе... Да тьху и растереть. Сегодня один, завтра другой, послезавтра вообще на другой язык переметнуться придётся, а через неделю из веба в приборостроение и RTOS, обычный процесс...

Comment: Хотелось бы так. Но пока надо заявится хоть в одной сфере...

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис, я к тому, что ни в одной сфере без нормальной базы ничего достичь не получится. Сайтоклёпство на готовых движках - вот потолок. Если хочется именно околовебового, то можно такое упражнение взять: например, написать SMTP-клиент с нуля, в качестве бонуса - с поддержкой TLS. На 3-4 языках. Сложно? OK, берём что попроще, например, AVL-деревья...Или, скажем, троичные. И пишем на них онлайн-переводчик  морзянки. А потом - с русского на морзянку. А потом - консольное приложение, да под разные ОС...

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис, если вы хотите быть востребованным на рынке - смотрите на то что сейчас активно используется, что развивается и т.д. Посмотрите в сторону других языков (для сравнения), неизвестных вам технологий (PostgreSQL, Tarantool, etc), статей по архитектуре приложения (в т.ч. микросервисы). В общем - просто не теряйте время и учите новое. А что именно - вы сами должны для себя определить.

Answer (score 1):

Если выбрать одного из больших ребят `Zend/Symfony/Larvel`, то ответ **любой**.

На самом деле откройте биржу труда и посмотрите по какому позиций больше.

Comment: Основные они +yii но тут как-то 50 на 50, конкретно выделить лидеров не смог, поэтому и прошу совета

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис  Если выбрать по количеству работ не подходит, то кинте монету.

На сегодняшний день все они настолько похожи что разницы нет особенно если свежие версии брать.(Кроме Yii)

Comment: Yii уступает? Слышал что на западном рынке не котируется.

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис Как человек живущий на западе скажу 2 вещи:
1) Когда искал работу то не встречал в объявлениях Yii.
2) Обычно если ищут на постоянку, а не короткий контракт/фриланс то не сильно важно какой фреймворк.

Comment: То есть важно понимание процесса а не конкретная реализация?

Comment: Да  реализация меняется

Answer (score 1):

Из PHP стоит обратить внимание на Laravel, он сейчас наиболее популярен, если ориентироваться на Upwork.

По поводу nosql, он не часто может пригодиться. В нете есть инфа про минусы и плюсы.

Если интересует bigdata, highload, то начать стоит с Go.

Comment: "*По поводу nosql, он не часто может пригодиться.*" - нет. "*Если интересует bigdata, highload, то начать стоит с Go.*" - нет.

Comment: Вам виднее, споры в интернете - цветные пиксели.

Answer (score 0):

Работал с Codeigniter, Yii. Для себя изучал Symfony2. Сейчас работаю с ASP.NET MVC.

По крайней мере в нашем проекте, много общего с Symfony. Symfony мне вообще понравился по сравнению с остальными. Но фреймворк не очень подходит для небольших сайтов. Он больше ориентирован на большие проекты.

Если Вы хотите делать сайты (сайты-визитки, корпоративные и т.п.) - то Yii2 (возможно Laravel, но я с ним не работал, ничего не могу сказать). Если у Вас душа лежит к каким-то большим корпоративным решениям - то Symfony будет лучше. А еще после нее легче (ИМХО) изучить .net (всяко бывает).

**UPDATE:**

Не работал с big-data, ничего не могу сказать по этому поводу. Но если Вас интересуют действительно большие проекты - это в основном Symfony и Zend.

А еще, Вам можно посмотреть в сторону строготипизированных C# или Java. Я изучал эту тему, когда был выбор остаться на PHP или уйти в проект на C#. Вообще со строгой типизацией поддерживать большие проекты проще.

Comment: Визитки и на cms норм идут...а хочется bigdata и серьезное чет... ребята с нашей конторы бесплатку(besplatka.ua) на yii писали. Вроде и бигдата да с другой стороны и не ахти результат вышел..

Comment: @ПобежимовБорис если вы до этого не работали ни с одним фреймворком, то (не обижайтесь) до биг даты вам как до луны. Начните с чего попроще, ту же симфони взять - это невероятное по длине приключение.

Answer (score 0):

просто большой набор терминов:
phalcon / yii / elastic (elk)

mysql / postgres / с++ /spark/cassandra/scilla/

дальше - кластеры/тыщи нод в дц - mesos и прочая распределенка

с базами данных все просто на самом деле, просто запихиваете в них ГОРУ данных и сразу видите бигдату, как запросы тормозят, как индексы не срабатывают и т.д.

насчет nosql - несоветую mongo.

php-фреймворки с бигдатой сами по себе не работают почти никогда  (phalcon может быть исключением, поскольку он расширение php на сях), они слишком тормозные.

обработка большой горы данных бывает пишется на native php, перекладывалки всякие, иногда с параллельной обработкой данных кучей скриптов-процессов, когда тормозит и вычисления - на плюсах с обработкой в памяти

это как бы для начала, поскольку у каждого своя бигдата, но если ваш код тормозит с таблицей на 100 мегов, то и на 100 гигов будет тормозить.

Comment: "*видите бигдату, как запросы тормозят, как индексы не срабатывают*" - это не биг дата. "*php-фреймворки с бигдатой сами по себе не работают почти никогда ... они слишком тормозные.*" - скорее всего вообще никогда, и не из-за скорости. "*обработка большой горы данных бывает пишется на native php, перекладывалки всякие, иногда с параллельной обработкой данных кучей скриптов-процессов, когда тормозит и вычисления - на плюсах с обработкой в памяти*" - нет, вас кто-то обманул.

Comment: ну выдайте свою версию, @Etki. я говорю о том, с чем сам сталкивался. о кодерах, которые забывают добавить индексы в дб, а раз в принципе запрос выполняется в таблице с двумя тестовыми записями - давай в прод. О том, как между демонами и скриптами распределяется нагрузка. Можно быть еще бигдатее, но ОП явно не готов в кластеры и облака

Comment: программист забыл добавить индексы или не смог подобрать базу данных для проекта - это вообще никакого отношения к биг дате не имеет.

Comment: если вы говорите про data science - то да. но у нас тут не data scientist, а начинающий.

Comment: определения не меняют своей сути от уровня изучающего. д и даже со скидками это никакая не биг дата.

Comment: ну и слава богу, что у вас бигдата бигдатее :-)